# split entries from source in dataframe - and put them all in one entry

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, split

a rather tricky question today. For me at least. I want to split the entries in the 'result', so that they get on a line each, but in the same DF entry. Can anyone help? Thanks!

heres my html

```
html ='''<div data-itf-inject="BeneficialNames"><div><ul class="bullet_list" data-six-show-max="2"><li>Mr. Fox</li><li>Mr. Gander</li><li style="display: none;">Mr. Daepp</li><li style="display: none;">Power&amp;Brothers Memory Fund III GP Ltd</li></ul><a data-six-showmore="true" href="#" style="display: inline-block;"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" title="Mehr anzeigen"></i> Mehr anzeigen</a></div></div>'''
```

I put it into BS:

```
h = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

then I get the text out.

```
BN = h.find('div', {'data-itf-inject': "BeneficialNames"}).text
```

Which returns a rather messy result.

Now, I'd like to put that in one DF-Entry, much like a multi index, but in one DF.

The rest of the DF exist already, with the addition it looks like this:

```
ISSUER    SHARE    BN
'Company' '95'     'Mr. FoxMr. GanderMr. DaeppPower&Brothers Memory Fund III GP Ltd'
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
ISSUER    SHARE    BN
'Company' '95'     'Mr. Fox'
                   'Mr. Gander'
                   'Mr. Daepp'
                   'Power&Brothers Memory Fund III GP Ltd'
```

What do I do? Thanks!

Comment: change your code to get_text - BN = h.find('div', {'data-itf-inject': "BeneficialNames"}).get_text(','). that should get you a delimiter for each item. you can then possibly do a str.split and explode. just a thought.

Comment: or even BN.strings will get you a generator that you can iterate on. Once concatenated, it is very hard to separate the names

Comment: You can do something close enough to what you need if you print your df in a Jupyter notebook. I can post it, if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution?

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
html ='''
<div data-itf-inject="BeneficialNames">
  <div>
    <ul class="bullet_list" data-six-show-max="2">
      <li>Mr. Fox</li>
      <li>Mr. Gander</li>
      <li style="display: none;">Mr. Daepp</li>
      <li style="display: none;">Power&amp;Brothers Memory Fund III GP Ltd</li>
    </ul><a data-six-showmore="true" href="#" style="display: inline-block;"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"
        title="Mehr anzeigen"></i> Mehr anzeigen</a>
  </div>
</div>
'''

doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
div = doc.select('div@data-itf-inject=BeneficialNames')
lis = div.ul.lis
print ([li.text for li in lis])
```

Result:

```
['Mr. Fox', 'Mr. Gander', 'Mr. Daepp', 'Power&amp;Brothers Memory Fund III GP Ltd']
```